# NHibernate ternary relationship mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE track
ID
name

CREATE TABLE people
ID
firstname

CREATE TABLE role
ID
name

CREATE TABLE track_people_role
track_id
people_id
role_id
```

and the following mapping files

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="App.Data.BusinessObjects" assembly="App.Data">
<class name="App.Data.BusinessObjects.Track, App.Data" table="track" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="name" />
</class>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="App.Data.BusinessObjects" assembly="App.Data">
<class name="App.Data.BusinessObjects.People, App.Data" table="people" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Firstname" column="firstname" />

</class>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="App.Data.BusinessObjects" assembly="App.Data">
<class name="App.Data.BusinessObjects.Role, App.Data" table="role" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="name" />
</class>
```

I am having a hard time trying to configure the mapping for track_people_role table. Could anybody help me out please?

I have the rows below in the intermediate table. The primary key is the combination of the three columns.

```
track_id  people_id  role_id  
14292     1          1  
14292     1          2  


track_id  people_id  role_id  
1200      1         1  
1200      2         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omitting all the subtleties, here's a working example.

Class:

```
class Track
{
    ...
    public virtual IDictionary<People, Role> PeopleRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="Track" ...>
  ...
  <map name="PeopleRoles" table="track_people_role">
    <key column="track_id"/>
    <map-key-many-to-many column="people_id" class="People"/>
    <many-to-many column="role_id" class="Role"/>
  </map>
</class>
```

As simple as it is, it contains many assumptions... don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi Diego, I update my original post to include some sample rows. With your solution track.PeopleRoles only returned the first row and when I tried to save (14292,1,3) i got an "An item with the same key has already been added" error

Comment: please disregard my comment about returning only the first row, though i still need help on how to save or update

Comment: Opened a new one for saving [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973709/nhibernate-saving-a-dictionary-in-a-ternary-relation)